# is it possible to make a php server response just to request coming from a special android app?

Tags: php, android

There is a link in my android app to receive data in json format from php server .
I'm wondering if it is possible to make a php server response just to request coming from my android app.
The reason to do this is preventing (hackers or someone who access to the link in my app by decompiling it) to use data provided by this link for their own apps.
I think Google is doing something like this for map , where they ask for SHA1 and provide a unique key for every app , so the map is just working on that app.

Answer (score 0):

Create some unique phone ID for each device and send it as Parma in your http request. If your post param=param_u_need do the action. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own token system in your server.Example::

**From your mobile app:** 
  While hitting API send header with secret code.

```
header.put("API-KEY","something-secret")*
```

**In your Server:**
  Only accept those request whose secret code matches.

```
if(API-KEY== something-secret){
  //valid request
}else{
  //invalid
}
```